# How many 6 digit numbers can be formed from 1-8 with some conditions?

Tags: combinatorics

- The digits 1,7 are near each other in every order, example 17 or 71 doesn't matter.
- The digits 2,5 are near each other in the given order, example 25 is allowed and 52 isn't.
- The digits can't be repeated.

Comment: Must $1,7$ occur in every number?  E.g. is $253468$ a valid number?  Same question for $2,5$.  If all of $1,7,2,5$ must occur, then pick the two remaining digits simultaneously.  Suppose they were $x,y$.  Then, arrange the digits $1,2,x,y$.  Once those are arranged, put the $7$ on either the left of the $1$ or the right, and put the $5$ on the right of the $2$.

Comment: I do believe they need to be always used. And i don't quite understand that finish, the total number still hasn't been found or am I missing something? Be as precise as possible! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment above, approach via multiplication principle.  I will have a running example of selections in grey.

- Pick the two remaining digits to be used other than $1,7,2,5$.  Call the smaller of the two selected $x$ and the larger of the selected $y$.  ($\color{grey}{\text{for example, the digits 3,4}}$)
- Arrange the digits $1,2,x,y$ ($\color{grey}{\text{for example, 12xy meaning in the running example 1234}}$)
- Choose to either place the $7$ immediately before the $1$ or immediately after the $1$ ($\color{grey}{\text{for example before, which in the running example is 71234}}$)
- Place the $5$ immediately after the $2$ ($\color{grey}{\text{ending with the final arrangement 712534}}$)

How many choices are there at each step?  Is every valid outcome counted in this fashion at least once?  exactly once?

---

If the correct interpretation of the problem is "**IF** $1$ or $7$ occurs then they must be adjacent" and "**IF** $2$ or $5$ occur, the other must also occur and they are in the order $25$", then break into cases based on which pairs of troublesome numbers are in use.

Comment: Is there a way how to get a exact number? I'm not getting this method

Comment: @LendritIbrahimi have you ever heard of the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)?  This is an application of that.  E.g. How many ways can you pick one flavor of ice cream and exactly two toppings where there are five flavors of ice cream and eight toppings available?  First step, choose the ice cream flavor, second step choose the two toppings.  The answer to the ice cream question is then $5\cdot \binom{8}{2}=5\cdot 28=140$.  Find the number of choices available for each step and multiply.

Comment: @LendritIbrahimi so, how many ways are there to pick the two remaining digits other than $1,7,2,5$?  You have *four* available digits and you want to **choose** *two* of them to use...  Continue figuring out how many choices are available at each step and multiply the number of choices together.  (*Note: sometimes steps are written where there is only one choice available*)

Comment: I don't know, I really can't figure this out

Comment: @LendritIbrahimi If you have $n$ objects and you want to **choose** $r$ of them, there are ["$n$ choose $r$"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)$=\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ ways to do this.  Now... I ask you again.  For the first step, we have *four* available digits and we want to **choose** *two* of them to use... how many ways can we accomplish that first step?

Comment: There are 6 ways to do that

Comment: Correct.  Now, what about the second step?  How many ways can you arrange $1,2,x,y$?  How about the third step?  How many ways can you choose to either put the $7$ before or put the $7$ after the one?  How about the fourth step?  How many ways can you specifically put the $5$ immediately after the $2$?  What is the product then of the number of choices at each step?  What then is the number of six digit numbers with the properties you desire?

Comment: X,Y should have 5 ways, because we avoid using 5,2,7,1 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48909/discussion-between-jmoravitz-and-lendrit-ibrahimi).